# selenium-maven : how to load Firefox or browser driver from resource folder

Tags: selenium, maven

I am working in Selenium. It is demo project. I am using maven for dependency management. I have downloaded the Gecko driver and has kept to folder location in local drive. But it will create a dependency to with local machine.

We have have folder in maven, called resource. I want to use that. I want to keep the Firefox driver there and want to load it from here.

**Maven Dependency**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-selemium</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!-- Add Following Lines in Your POM File -->
    <properties>
        <selenium.version>2.53.1</selenium.version>
        <testng.version>6.9.10</testng.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Java Code**

```
public class PG1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String baseUrl = "https://www.google.co/";

//        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Users/Dell/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64/geckodriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:/Drive_H/projects/selenium/src/main/resources/geckodriver-firefox.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

[image: Project structure image]

I have tried with this line but error : unable to load driver.

`System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver-firefox.exe");`

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to get the project user directory path and then access the desired executable.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\main\\resources\\geckodriver-firefox.exe");
```